# Pandas: Encode long row values with shorter names and use another column values as a part of the name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, apply

I have a big data set with tons of rows. I have one column in that data set with long row values. I want to rename these row values with shorter names and use the previous column values as a part of the name. How can I do this with Pandas?

I have a dataset like this:

[image]

And want an output like this:

[image]

Comment: @EBDS I have posted my question as a new post here

Comment: You got your answer already ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) function which encodes the different patterns of objects as an enumerated type (with different serial numbers), as follows:

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'] + 'U' + df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1).astype(str)
```

Since each different value of `Col1` need to reset the serial number from 1, we make use of [`.GroupBy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) to help with this.

#### Demo

**Data Input**

```
data = {'Col1': ['C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C3'],
        'Col2': ['XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYY', 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ', 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ', 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ', 'KKKKKKKKKKKKKK', 'MMMMMMMMMMMMMM']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)   

print(df) 


  Col1            Col2
0   C1  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
1   C1  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2   C1  YYYYYYYYYYYYYY
3   C2  ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
4   C2  ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
5   C2  ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
6   C2  KKKKKKKKKKKKKK
7   C3  MMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)

  Col1  Col2
0   C1  C1U1
1   C1  C1U1
2   C1  C1U2
3   C2  C2U1
4   C2  C2U1
5   C2  C2U1
6   C2  C2U2
7   C3  C3U1
```

Comment: @Me0002 The solution is only one line: `df['Col2'] = df['Col1'] + 'U' + df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1).astype(str)` where all actions are done automatically.  The dictionary, I just put it as a demo how to create your sample data based on the picture you showed.